# selecting best way for deploying MongoDB on Cloud Platform?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas, google-cloud-launcher

I am using google cloud platform for my project and planning to use mongodb cloud service.
I am confused in selecting the MongoDB on Cloud Platform. 
I had read [this link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-mongodb#deploying_mongodb) which tells 3 ways through which we can deploy mongodb.

Please help me out for selecting best option.

Answer (score 0):

## Recommendation

I have used all three options for deploying MongoDB on the Cloud Platform and believe the **Cloud Launcher for MongoDB** is by far your best choice.

## Justification

I would like to address each of the three deployment options and explain my reasoning.

#### Cloud Launcher for MongoDB

The Cloud Launcher for MongoDB is what I would recommend. It's much simpler than creating a MongoDB database in any other way, since there are presets and you click through a nice UI. This was the way I created my first MongoDB database and felt pretty confident throughout the setup process.

### MongoDB Cloud Manager

The MongoDB Cloud Manager is a more advanced version of the Cloud Launcher for MongoDB. It supports "more complex deployments... ...such as complex replica sets or sharded clusters." You will be able to work your way towards these complex deployments with the Cloud Launcher for MongoDB, without being overwhelmed immediately.

### Google Cloud Deployment Manager

The Google Cloud Deployment Manager "lets you automate the setup of [the] MongoDB Cloud Manager." The MongoDB Cloud Manager is already more complicated than the Cloud Launcher for MongoDB, so there is no reason for you to automate deployments at this point.

[**Documentation Quoted in this Answer**](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-mongodb#deploying_mongodb)